# How to determine the Z order of multiple visible forms in Delphi?

Tags: delphi

Using Delphi 7. There are, among other components, 4 non-modal visible forms over a TPanel (the TPanel is the parent of the forms). I use Show, Hide, BringToFront, SendToBack on the various forms and it works fine.

The problem is that at any point in time I would like to programmatically determine the Z order of the forms. For example, Form2 is on top, behind that is Form3, then Form1, and last is Form4.

Or put it in a slightly different way: given any two non-modal, visible forms, e.g. Form2 and Form3, how to determine programmatically which one is above the other?

I tried Screen.Forms, but it doesn't work -- it always gives me the forms in the same order, regardless of the actual visible Z-order of the forms.

I read about the Windows functions GetTopWindow and GetNextWindow but before I try to use that, I'd like to know if there is a simpler way. Especially if I just have two forms with the same parent, is there a simple way to know which of them is above the other?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`GetWindow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633515(v=vs.85).aspx) passing `GW_HWNDNEXT` and `GW_HWNDPREV` to traverse the Z-order.

You say that you don't want to use this method and look for something simpler. There is nothing simpler.

Comment: I suppose you mean GetNextWindow? As I wrote in my question, I'm looking for a simpler way than that.

Comment: No, I mean GetWindow

Comment: OK, I now see that I can use both GetTopWindow/GetNextWindow and also GetWindow with various parameters. That seems the way to go. Thanks.